# Conundrum with POST and GET on Android app

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to gain some information from my localhost database via my android app. I am using the HttpUrlConnection class to create objects that read/write from/to the database.

I am having this problem now, because the HttpUrlConnection object am trying to create needs to read and write at the same time to a PHP file hosted on the localhost database. I see that the HttpUrlConnection class has a method setRequestMethod, which if I want to write to the database i will use setRequestMethod("POST") and if I want to read from the database i will use 
setRequestMethod("GET"). I need to do both at the same time. I need to initialize a variable in a PHP file with the POST method, and then search and read row values on the database based on the initialized POSTED variable.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You should always use POST. And let php just echo and your android code read the returned echos from the input stream. You created yourself a problem that does not exist.

Comment: `HttpUrlConnection class to create objects that read/write from/to the database`. Impossible. HtmlUrlConnection can only communicate with the php script. What the php script does with it is out of reach fot HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: `the HttpUrlConnection object am trying to create needs to read and write at the same time to a PHP file `. Wrong description. HttpUrlConnection sends some data to a php script. And then the php script sends some data back. That the php sript has to write to the database and after that (not at the same time) reads from the database and echos data back to HttpUrlConnection is no problem at all. Its quit normal.

Comment: So you are saying to use setRequestMethod("POST") with an inputstream which should allow me to read values from the database. @greenapps

Comment: No which allows you to read the echos from the php script. And indead the php script could echo values from a database.

Comment: the way I've read values from the database is by creating arrays with json_decode. Then, on my android code I create JSON arrays or JSON objects that get the string values from key/value pairs on the array created by json_decode on the php script. Could you give me an example with echo, seems more easier. Now, how would I read these values if I need to get them on my android code? @greenapps

Comment: Just post your code. But again i think you are creating a problem that does not exist. And there is nothing left of your first problem? Hows that possible?

Comment: I will in a moment. I will be trying to setRequestMethod("POST") with an inputstream in order to read values. I will test this out. @greenapps

Answer (score 0):

The response from server is not depend on GET or POST method. So you can receive the response in both cases, just design your server like this:

```
$value1 = $_REQUEST["name"];
$value2 = $_REQUEST["name2"];
...
do_some_thing();
...
$sth = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
//don't care it's POST or GET request.
```

See different between GET and POST method: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp